# Temporarily exclude points in plotly graph

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, r-plotly, ggplotly

In the following `plotly` example (taken from [here](https://plot.ly/r/graphing-multiple-chart-types/)), is it possible to introduce a function that allows the user to click on a point to 'grey it out', so it would be excluded from the 'active' dataset, and the loess fit line would automatically adjust to the new dataset? The point(s) could then be clicked again to bring them back into the 'active' data set.  Could be tricky. As the comments suggest it will likely require `shiny`, but I’m having trouble figuring out how.

```
   library(plotly)
   library(broom)

m <- loess(mpg ~ disp, data = mtcars)

p <- plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~disp, color = I("black")) %>%
  add_markers(y = ~mpg, text = rownames(mtcars), showlegend = FALSE) %>%
  add_lines(y = ~fitted(loess(mpg ~ disp)),
            line = list(color = 'rgba(7, 164, 181, 1)'),
            name = "Loess Smoother") %>%
  add_ribbons(data = augment(m),
              ymin = ~.fitted - 1.96 * .se.fit,
              ymax = ~.fitted + 1.96 * .se.fit,
              line = list(color = 'rgba(7, 164, 181, 0.05)'),
              fillcolor = 'rgba(7, 164, 181, 0.2)',
              name = "Standard Error") %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(title = 'Displacement (cu.in.)'),
         yaxis = list(title = 'Miles/(US) gallon'),
         legend = list(x = 0.80, y = 0.90))

# Create a shareable link to your chart
# Set up API credentials: https://plot.ly/r/getting-started
chart_link = api_create(p, filename="multiple-loess-se")
chart_link
```

[image]

Comment: I do not think this is possible without `shiny`. What you are searching for is the `plotly_click`-function (cf. https://plot.ly/r/shiny-coupled-events/). That however usually links two graphs. You have one. I can imagine if you do two graphs and link them that it might work. But if you manage it without using `shiny` is another question entirely

Comment: maybe this could help you started: https://community.plot.ly/t/removing-or-restyling-specific-points-in-a-trace-not-an-entire-trace/7884/4

Comment: Thanks to both for the tips. It’s a good start.  :)

Comment: @MLavoie your code snippet only works if I use `htmlwidgets::onRender`

Comment: @5th could you please provide a link if you know one where I might be able to get started with this using `shiny`?

Comment: Sorry I only saw this late - here you go: https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/