# R: ggplot, plotly and auto-adjust of a Stacked bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-plotly, ggplotly

I'm facing this problem with `ggplot2` and `plotly` packages with R.
I'm creating a stacked bar chart, and, first of all, my data:

```
# here my data
family <- c('one','one','one','one','one','one','one','one',
            'two','two','two','two','two','two','two','two')

group <- c('alpha','beta','alpha','beta','alpha','beta',
            'alpha','beta','alpha','beta','alpha','beta',
          'alpha','beta','alpha','beta')

field <- c('a','a','b','b','c','c','d',
           'd','a','a','b','b','c','c','d','d')

value <- sample(1:10, 16, replace =TRUE)

data <- data.frame(family, group, field, value)

remove(family,group,field,value)
```

Then, I created my stacked barchart with `ggplot2`:

```
# here the plot
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = group, y = value, fill =reorder(field,value))) 
p <- p + geom_bar(position = "fill",stat = "identity")
p <- p + ggtitle("A simple example") 
p <- p + theme(axis.text.x =  element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))+ guides(fill=FALSE)
p <- p + facet_grid(family~.)
```

Lastly, I put it as a `plotly` output:

```
ggplotly(p)
remove(data)
```

The result is good:

[image]

**My issue is**: if you choose one of the occurrences on the legend you have this (choosing d):

[image]

I really would like that if you choose for example the d, the plot "returns" to a 100% stacked barplot, recalculating the percentage logically. Is it possible? If so, how?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it need to be `plotly` only?. Because your code poses two issues: 1. You need to compute percentages 2. You need to update that data for every selection. In some way your question is similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49996086/temporarily-exclude-points-in-plotly-graph#comment87079634_49996086

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I'm knitting in a Markdown file a plotly object like that, and I'd like to use it without shiny if it's possible.

Comment: I think that isn't possible. You can do a linked plotly graph. Technically you could try using some `javascript` - but no idea how